# Scanner with delimiter "\\Z" has no next element at first calling

Tags: java, input, delimiter

Good day! I use such part of code

```
File file = new File(someFilePath);
    Scanner sc;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return "";
    }
    sc.useDelimiter("\\Z");
    System.out.println("file : " + file.getName() + " " + sc.hasNext() + " " + sc.delimiter());
    String fileString = sc.next();
```

I get error `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException` at last line of this piece of code.
And the output is `file : 758279215_profile.txt false \Z`, so the delimiter is correct, file exists (and it's not empty, I've checked it), but it has no next element for some reason (and as I think next element should be and it should be the whole text in the file). What's wrong and how to fix it? Thank you!

ADDED:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line = "";
    while (line != null) {
        try {
            line = br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

returns content of a file (text file with content edited as JSON text) and null (the last itteration of the loop)

Comment: Could you try the same code without setting the delimiter?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yep, output is `file : 758279215_profile.txt false \p{javaWhitespace}+`, error is the same

Comment: It looks like the system is looking for the file in a different location from where you are checking it to confirm that it is non-empty. The file is there, but it is empty. Try `System.out.println(file.length());` to see if it's zero.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `file.length()` returns 1331 bytes

Comment: What?.. This makes zero sense whatsoever! Could you try reading from that file without using `Scanner`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yep, for me it makes no sense too. I've tried to read it with `BufferedReader` and added this remark to the question.

Answer (score 0):

it could be locale issue.
try `export LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8`

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: i had the same issue and i tried to rewrite this part with another method.  compiling passed but the unit test failed because of encoding issue. Then i tried to change my `LC_ALL` setting. Magically everything is fine now (with both code). You can check locale description in docs. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html